# Change css attributes

Tags: javascript, css

Using DOM manipulation need to change this:

```
ul.tabbernav li
{
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 display: inline; 
}
```

to this:

```
ul.tabbernav li
{
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
display: none;
}
```

Only using pure javascript functions. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this, if you want pure javascript....

```
 function changeCss(){ 
    var selector = document.getElementById('your_selector')
    selector.style.display = "none"
 }
```

and then you can call it when you need to use it.

and you canuse this if you have access to some jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.some_button_or_link').on('click',function(){
       $('your_selector').style('display' , 'none')
   })
})
```

More so you can use classes (adding and removing) like this:

If you have your css like this :

```
  .hidden{display : none}
```

then you can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.some_button_or_link').on('click',function(){
   $('your_selector').addClass('hidden')
   })
 })
```

and if you want to re-add the class

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.some_button_or_link').on('click',function(){
       $('your_selector').removeClass('hidden')
     })
  })
```

and then note that where I have used .on('click') you can as well use other kinds of events. Try and post back. Cheers!

Comment: @Farhad Mammadli check this  [link](http://jsbin.com/gokaciyaju/edit?html,js,output)  have created a working example of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't aim to change the css but rather add or remove a class to the html element, which would correspond to a css with display:none.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2q5310os/1/) :

css :

```
.hidden { display:none; }
```

javascript :

```
document.getElementById("hideMe").classList.toggle("hidden");
```

Comment: Added an example with a link to a jsfiddle. Jim Fahad's answer is probably better if you only need to change the display though

Comment: @FarhadMammadli you can't obviously. Look for Ernest Muraguri's answer which will change the element style rather than its class.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ul.tabbernav li').css('display', 'none');
```

More efficiently:

```
<script>
(function(){
  $('.ul.tabbernav li').css('display', 'none !important');
})();
</script>
```

Comment: And if you want to hide a specific list item you can use css3 nth-child selector, Like if you wanna hide 5th li only the you can write like this:

    $('.ul.tabbernav li:nth-child(5)').css('display', 'none !important');

Comment: jQuery is nice, but the OP didn't indicate jQuery, so you need to show a non-jQuery method.